# POI XWPF pagesizes via CTPageSz are off

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I'm trying to insert tables into a XWPF docx via Apache POI (3.12 with ooxml-schemas 1.1).

I'm using

```
CTTblWidth oWidth = oTable.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblW();
oWidth.setType(STTblWidth.PCT);
oWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(iWidth));
```

to set the width of my table.
By trial and error iWidth = 5000 seems like a reasonable value.

I tried to get the pagewidth dynamically via

```
CTBody oBody = m_oDocx.getDocument().getBody();
if (!oBody.isSetSectPr()) oBody.addNewSectPr();
CTSectPr oSect = oBody.getSectPr();
if (!oSect.isSetPgSz()) oSect.addNewPgSz();    
CTPageSz pageSize = oSect.getPgSz();
BigInteger oPageSize.getW();
```

But this returns with a value of 11906 for DINA4 which is far off.
Even when substracting the margins via something like this:

```
oPageSize.getW().subtract(oSect.getPgMar().getRight()).subtract(oSect.getPgMar().getLeft())
```

I'm still far off the mark.

Can anyone give me a hint what I'm missing here, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
oWidth.setType(STTblWidth.PCT);
```

use

```
oWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
```

STTblWidth.PCT is used to specify width in fiftieths of a percent.

STTblWidth.DXA is used to specify width in twentieths of a point. 72 points makes an inch.

Comment: Thanks. Thats it!  
I still don't get why Percent counts to 5000 though.

Comment: Just a guess. Are you getting 5000 PCT same as 50.00%?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. 5000 was roughly the width of the writing area in a default DinA4 page (2.5cm margins).

Comment: I have updated my answer. See the link [Points, inches and Emus: Measuring units in Office Open XML](https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml/) for all types of measurement units in Office Open XML.